# How to use glUniform1f in this example?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textureview

I've searched for, read and tried many different examples on how to pass a value into a GLSL program. But sadly every try was a fail :(

What I plan to do is very simple: Just a little open gl 3d animation inside my Android App. Resulting from my GUI design I prefer to use a TextureView as OpenGl Surface. I found some code that fits perfect to my project.

But my problem seems to be completely inside [this example](https://github.com/dalinaum/TextureViewDemo/blob/master/src/kr/gdg/android/textureview/GLTriangleActivity.java).

When I compile and run it, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. Draw one single triangle on screen.

Then I modified the Vertex Shader like this:

```
final String vertexShaderSource = 
   "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
   "attribute float myValue;\n" +
   "void main () {\n" +
         "vec4 oo;\n"+
         "oo[0] = position[0];\n"+
         "oo[1] = position[1] * myValue;\n"+
         "oo[2] = position[2];\n"+
         "oo[3] = position[3];\n"+
         "gl_Position = oo;\n" +
   "}";
```

And now, I want to pass a value to the attribute `myValue`.

So here are my modifications to the run method.

```
public void run() {
   initGL();

   int attribPosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,
           "position");
   checkGlError();

   int valuePosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,
           "myValue");
   checkGlError();

   System.out.println("att id:"+ attribPosition 
           + " val id:" + valuePosition);

//[...]

   while (true) {
       checkCurrent();

       mVertices.position(0);
       GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attribPosition, 3,
                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVertices);
       checkGlError();

       GLES20.glUniform1f(valuePosition, 1.5f);
       checkGlError();
    //[...]           
    }
}
```

From my understanding, this should expand the triangle on y-axis with factor 1.5f. But it is not working.
The ouput of my debug line is:

```
I/System.out(22427): att id:1 val id:0
```

So these should be correct locations since none of them has -1 content.
But by passing the value `1.5f` to `myValue` with `glUniform1f`, the only result I can achieve is the continuous `OpenGL Error 0x502` output. There is no triangle anymore, because the shader script will not receive the `1.5f` and will use the value 0 to expand it.

I really hope someone could explain me, how to get this done. Because it is something so fundamental I think I am missing something very obvious here.

Comment: Check if any OpenGL error is produced during your shader execution and update the question with it.

Comment: There are no other OpenGL errors. And the example checks a lot for errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mixing the concepts of `attribute` and `uniform` variables.

Since you declared your `myValue` variable as an `attribute` in the shader, you need to set the value with `glVertexAttrib()`:

```
glVertexAttrib1f(valuePosition, 1.5f);
```

If you want it to be a `uniform`, change the declaration in the vertex shader to:

```
uniform float myValue;
```

and the call to get the location to:

```
int valuePosition = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "myValue");
```

Both solutions are valid. As the name suggests, `uniform` variables are ideal for values that do not change much, i.e. they ideally stay the same for the whole frame. `attribute` variables are more efficient for values that change frequently while rendering a frame.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a uniform before you set it through `glUniform1f`. So, make the `myValue` as uniform.

```
uniform float myValue;
```

The next thing is you need its location to bind a value. You can do that using `glGetUniformLocation` function.

```
int valuePosition = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "myValue");
```

And finally, you set a uniform for that location using the `glUniform` functions.

```
GLES20.glUniform1f(valuePosition, 0.5f);
```

And you can achieve the same result even using attributes. Attributes are efficient for constantly changing values, whereas uniforms are efficient for less changing values.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying following:

`"attribute float myValue;\n"` 
->
`"uniform float myValue;\n"`

and

`int valuePosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "myValue");` -> `int valuePosition = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "myValue");`

Also, have a look at following documentation page, which shows more cleaner way of translating and scaling vertices.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html